# what does mellanox interrupt mlx4-async@pci:0000 ... means?

Tags: operating-system, irq, infiniband, mellanox

I'm using an InfiniBand Mellanox card `[ConnectX VPI PCIe 2.0 5GT/s - IB QDR / 10GigE]` with OFED version 4-1.0.0 on an ubuntu 3.13.0 running on a x86_64 computer with 4 cores.

Here is the result of `ibstat` on my computer

```
CA 'mlx4_0'
CA type: MT26428
Number of ports: 1
Firmware version: 2.8.600
Hardware version: b0
Node GUID: 0x0002c903004d58ee
System image GUID: 0x0002c903004d58f1
Port 1:
    State: Active
    Physical state: LinkUp
    Rate: 40
    Base lid: 1
    LMC: 0
    SM lid: 1
    Capability mask: 0x02510868
    Port GUID: 0x0002c903004d58ef
    Link layer: InfiniBand
```

and my `/proc/interrupts` looks like this :

```
  67:      17923       4654          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mlx4-async@pci:0000:01:00.0
  68:      26696          0         54          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mlx4_0-0
  69:          0         34         23          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mlx4_0-1
  70:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mlx4_0-2
  71:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mlx4_0-3
```

I read that each `mlx4_0-x` interrupts are associated to each CPU. My question is : what does the first interrupt `mlx4-async@pci:0000:01:00.0` means ? I experiment that when the `opensm` deamon is not yet running, this interrupt occur every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

mlx4-async is used for asynchronous events other than completion events, e.g. link events, catastrophic events, cq overrun, etc.

the interrupt is handled by the adapter driver and depending on the event different modules are activated, such a link event notifications or cleanups due to asynchronous errors.